# IF TRUE then Variable name

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean-logic

I have a series of TRUE and FALSE variables representing search findings, ex: Cellphones, Knifes, Money, etc. My goal is to change the values TRUE for the name of the variable. Note that I would like to do this for 15 or more variables.

```
df <- data.frame(cellphone = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 money = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 knife = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 whatIneed = c("cellphone", "cellphone", "", "cellphone",""))

  cellphone money knife whatIneed
1      TRUE FALSE  TRUE cellphone
2      TRUE FALSE  TRUE cellphone
3     FALSE FALSE FALSE          
4      TRUE  TRUE FALSE cellphone
5     FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: A simple `ifelse` statement also does the job: `ifelse(df$cellphone == T, "cellphone", "")`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have many variables and would like to find a fastest way, perhaps a loop.

Comment: @akrun's answer is I think the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, an option is to loop over the subset of columns that are logical rowwise, get the first column name based on the logical vector

```
df$whatIneed <- apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) names(x)[x][1])
df$whatIneed
[1] "cellphone" "cellphone" NA          "cellphone" NA
```

---

If we want to do this individually on each column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.logical),
      ~ case_when(.x ~ cur_column()), .names = "{.col}_name"))
```

-output

```
cellphone money knife whatIneed cellphone_name money_name knife_name
1      TRUE FALSE  TRUE cellphone      cellphone       <NA>      knife
2      TRUE FALSE  TRUE cellphone      cellphone       <NA>      knife
3     FALSE FALSE FALSE                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4      TRUE  TRUE FALSE cellphone      cellphone      money       <NA>
5     FALSE FALSE FALSE                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I need to do this for all variables. if the value is TRUE on the variable the return the variable name.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! The first clause (where(is.logical)) filters the desired columns correct? What about if there are other unrelated  logical/Boolean variables I don't want to include? Thank you!!!

Comment: @MarvinAliaga you can use any of the select-helpers for selecitng columns.  Here, it was obvious that you want to apply it on logical columns.  Suppose you want to select specificially use `across(c(cellphone, money), ~ ..` or `across(c(cellphone:knife), ~` if it is in  a range etc

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!